# Crossing branches with forest or TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, linguistics

I'm very new to LaTeX and especially to `forest`. I need to create the tree in the picture, which I did with `xyling`, in `forest` or TikZ. I can't solve the problem with any of these. My problem is how to create crossing branches. Has anyone any tips?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. For future questions it would be helpful to provide a compilable minimal document showing what you've tried so far rather than just posting an image. For example, you could have posted your version of the tree in the picture with the NP node dominated by VP, which although not what you want, would give people something to work with.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy to do with `forest`. You can use `no edge` to remove the edge from a node, and then manually draw the crossing branch.

Disclaimer: As a syntactician I don't endorse the following tree. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}where n children=0{tier=word}{} 
[S,name=S 
    [NP [D [die] ] [N [Mutter] ]]
    [VP 
        [V [singt]]
        [NP [D [die] ] [N [Kinder] ]]
        [NP,name=NP,no edge [D [jeden]] [N [Abend]]]
        [PP
            [P [in] ]
            [NP [D [den] ] [N [Schlaf] ]]
        ]
        ]
]
\draw (S.south) -- (NP.north west); % or use (NP.north) 
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'm sorry I didn't post my work to make things easier, I really didn't think about it. I don't like the syntax of this tree either, but my professor wants them done this way...

Comment: @MartinaSapienza If this answer solved your problem, it's helpful to others to "Accept" it by clicking on the green checkmark icon beside it.